# What kind of personal body scanning equipment can you legally buy?

Tags: mri, ultrasounds

I would like a personal body scanner.

What kind of things can I buy that's legal and safe?

Is a ultrasound safe and what kind of things can it see?

I think an MRI scanner would be a bit too expensive.

Comment: Yes I imagine an MRI would be a bit expensive. Are you planning to get training on how to use any of this? It takes years to learn how to interpret medical imaging.

Comment: @Chris I just want to look at my bones to see what they look like. Is that illegal?

Comment: It might be, depending on where you live. From what I can see you can buy an ultrasound scanner. However, x-rays (as used in x-ray and CT) are ionising radiation and this pose a health hazard, so their use is likely tightly regulated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because legality is off topic here and safety is a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the US, medical device sales are regulated by the FDA much like drugs.

Like drugs, some items are permitted for over-the-counter (OTC) sale to the public (for example, bandages and thermometers). Others can only be sold to medical professionals. Diagnostic devices that require a professional to interpret are very unlikely to be available OTC.

Other countries have similar rules according to whatever regulatory body has jurisdiction.

Comment: It's health and safety gone mad.

Comment: @zooby The alternative before the FDA was all kinds of snake oil and crank treatments sold as medicine while being worthless or unsafe. There are still examples of that today via some loopholes, but it's vastly better than it was. Might seem "mad" to you but it's quite purposeful.

Comment: @zooby Are you aware that x-ray machines contain nuclear material that can be used to make a dirty bomb? Are you aware you can completely destroy human tissue with an incorrectly used x-ray? It's not safety gone mad.